# Environment Variables in MacOS Big Sur for Maven

Tags: bash, maven, environment-variables, macos-big-sur

I have **MacOS Big Sur** and inside of the /Users/us-guest/ doesn't exist the

> .bash_profile

and I need to add *environment global PATH* for maven, however, I have installed Java 11 and I don't need to set up any environment variable and without problem, if you write `java -version` my console respond and in fact, if you use `printenv` I can see the setup variables current in the system.

> Why do I need to set up an environment variable for maven and not for
> **Java**?
>
> Can I create a file **bash_profile** without affecting the environment
> variables established in the system?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfo18.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfmmY.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmvyI.png

Comment: See the bash man page.  The section _INVOCATION_ describes, which files bash processes (and in which order), Depending on which of the file you have a certain PATH definition, a particular bash will contain it or not.

Comment: In addition, MacOS has an additional place for such definitions, which is independend of bash. See [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/107787/how-to-set-system-wide-environment-variables-on-os-x-mavericks), in particular the answer given by _ColonelMode_.